# How to get all message from a youtube live stream

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I want the get all the message from a youtube live stream. Even the once that are held back for review. Is this possible?

I made a request to *https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/liveChat/messages* but i do not get the messages back that are held back for review. I would like the ability to get those messages and allow or deny them.

Comment: I would like to help you but I am unable to generate messages that are *help back for review*, swear words from another account are just not shown on the livechat from the live host account point of view. Do you have a way to produce messages that are *held back for review*?

Comment: Yea i got it to hold back the message. But it will now show up in the api.

Comment: By *do you have*, I meant please give me your method to produce messages that are *held back for review*.

Comment: Starting my owner live broadcast and poste messages. I just tested some words until one was held back.